# How many permutations of any 7 letters contain the string bea?

Tags: probability, permutations

Bea has written a computer program that randomly generates 7 letters of the alphabet without replacement, what is the chance a random list will contain her name, such as, 'cbeadfk'. Answer as a fully simplified fraction.

My solution is:
There are 26 letters in the alphabet and 7 are chosen each time, therefore the number of possible permutations is,
26P7 = 3315312000.
We are interested in strings containing B, E, A in that order so we take those letters out of the alphabet and string, leaving 4 positions with 23 letters to choose from. The string bea can appear in 5 different permutations for each arrangement of the remaining 4 letters. So the amount of strings containing bea is
(23P4)*5 = 1062600
favourable/total = 1062600/3315312000=1/3120

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks, this was my first ever post and I did not expect anyone to be that fast. i had to write the question for an assignment and I had no way of checking my answer.

Comment: No problem.  Your calculation is clear and thorough.  Might be worth noting that it gets a bit more complicated if you allow replacement, since then there are a few strings that contain $BEA$ twice.  If you are looking for practice, you might want to try that calculation.

Comment: With replacement there's 2284932 strings that contain bea, making it a 2284932/26^7 chance?

Comment: How do you get that?  For a first pass, your method would still say there were $5$ places to start the $BEA$ and since the other four slots can be occupied by any letter, you get $5\times 26^4=2284880$ which is close to, but not the same as what you wrote.  However, even then you have got to subtract off the number of strings in which $BEA$ appears twice as you counted them twice.

Comment: Whoops I did  5×26^4 + 2×26, I guess I should've done 5×26^4 - 2×26.

Comment: But there are three patterns for the strings that contain $BEA$ twice.  Namely, $BEABEA*, \,BEA*BEA, \, *BEABEA$.

Comment: @MatthiasHaydon-Schulz If it concerns "with replacement" you can go for finding $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^5B_i)$ by means of [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) where $B_i$ is the event that the $i$-th letter is a "b". Lots of terms will take value $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to calculate it:

Choosing $m$ letters in sequence without replacement from the $26$ letters, you have probability $m/26$ to choose the letter B. But in order for the seven letters to include “BEA” the letter B has to be among the first **five** letters chosen. The total probability of that is $5/26.$

Given that B is among the first five letters, the probability that the next letter is E is $1/25.$ Given B in the first five letters followed by E, the probability that the next letter is A is $1/24.$

So altogether the probability of “BEA” within the first seven letters is
$$
\frac5{26} \cdot \frac1{25} \cdot \frac1{24}
= \frac1{3120},
$$
which agrees with your answer. I also agree that your method is correct. (It is not an accident that both methods get the same answer!)

Comment: Thanks, I think your method is a lot more elegant so thank you.

Comment: Both methods are good. It is nice to have more than one tool to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of $bea????$: $\dfrac{1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}{26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}$.

Probability of $?bea???$ : $\dfrac{23\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}{26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}$.

Probability of $??bea??$ : $\dfrac{23\cdot22\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot21\cdot20}{26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}$.

Probability of $???bea?$ : $\dfrac{23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot20}{26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}$.

Probability of $????bea$ : $\dfrac{23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}{26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20}$.

Hence in total,

$$\frac{5}{26\cdot25\cdot24}=\frac1{3120}.$$